# In php laravel, can a static method return boolean?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am writing a method in my model to return true or flase. Following is my code.

```
  public static function isSerialRequired($id)
        {
            $data = static::where('user_id', $id)->orderBy('id','desc')->get();

            data processing code... 

            if (condition for true)
                return true;
            return false;

        }
```

I am getting the below error.

**The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given**

Comment: The problem is not this method and that it returns a boolean but rather what you do with the return value afterwards. I suppose you return it from your controller action?

Comment: I wrote this method in a model.

Comment: I know. Again, this method is not the problem. The problem is what you do with the return value. Show me the code where you call the function.

Comment: @lukasgeiter  Thanks got the error. return ( $attempt->isSerialRequired($request['user_ID'])) was in my controller...

Comment: And what are you trying to do? (In other words: how should the response look like?)

Comment: return ( $attempt->isSerialRequired($request['user_ID']))? view('take_serial') : view('message') ; 

I have to write the above code in my controller.

Comment: Looks like a problem with the parentheses. Try this: `return ($attempt->isSerialRequired($request['user_ID']) ? view('take_serial') : view('message'));`

Comment: Thanks your solutions are always helpful.. Problem solved...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not this method and that it returns a boolean but rather what you do with the return value afterwards. Apparently you accidentally returned the result of the method from your controller and Laravel doesn't like that because it tries to convert whatever your controller returns to a string.

---

This was the problem:

```
return ($attempt->isSerialRequired($request['user_ID']))? view('take_serial') : view('message');
```

One parenthesis too much, this works:

```
return ($attempt->isSerialRequired($request['user_ID']) ? view('take_serial') : view('message'));
```